# Using a helper method in a mailer that is defined in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

The helper method `current_user` is defined and made available as a helper in `ApplicationController` like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user
    def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
    end
end
```

My question is how I can use the `current_user` helper method in a mailer template (obviously it will always return `nil`, but I'm trying to render a partial that depends on it).

Normally when I want to use helpers in a mailer, I do something like `add_template_helper(SongsHelper)`, but since the helper is defined in a class instead of a module I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 4):

I like to pass the user in a variable, then just use that in the template. It passes off the `current_user` call to the controller (where I usually deliver mail from).

Another solution is to put `current_user` and supporting methods into a module and mix it into both ApplicationController and also use with the `helper` method in your class that inherits from ActionMailer::Base. Take a look at [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper) if you're interested in this method.

Comment: I passed return value of controller method in a mailer method parameter. `UserMailer.invitation(@invitation, current_organization).deliver` where current_organization is defined in `ApplicationController`